# How can I remove a contact CompleteName.Title with EWS managed api v1.1?

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Using EWS managed api v1.1, I can successfully save/set the contact "Title" or honorific (if you prefer) to a non-empty value, but I can't figure out how to remove or set it back to an empty string/null.

I've tried to set an empty value **and** I've tried to remove the extended property.  Here is relevant code.

```
var titleDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A45, MapiPropertyType.String);

// works when set to a non-empty string value
ewsContact.SetExtendedProperty(titleDef, "Mr.");

// throws null argument exception when set to String.Empty or null
ewsContact.SetExtendedProperty(propDefinition, String.Empty);

// isRemoved is equal to false and the value doesn't change
var isRemoved = ewsContact.RemoveExtendedProperty(titleDef);
```

I've also tried to use a different overload on the ExtendedPropertyDefinition as mentioned in [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863364), but it didn't change my end result for removing the property.  I'm not sure I understand the difference in the two signatures for the constructor.

```
var titleDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(new Guid("{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"), 0x3A45, MapiPropertyType.String);

// isRemoved is equal to false and the value doesn't change
var isRemoved = ewsContact.RemoveExtendedProperty(titleDef);
```

**Brute Force Work-Around**

I suppose I could take a complete copy of the contact (without the title) and delete the original, but that seems a bit over the top and would probably cause other bugs.

Comment: Did you create the original [Contact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg274394%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) entry or did you just modify an existing?

Comment: I'm modifying an existing contact using the `Contact.Bind()` method with the `ItemId` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EWS lets you assign [Extended Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633691%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) without first binding them. However, to remove an Extended Property - you need to include it in your initial binding call `PropertySet`. The following worked for me...

```
 var titleDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A45, MapiPropertyType.String);
 Contact contact = Contact.Bind(service, id, new PropertySet(titleDef));
 contact.RemoveExtendedProperty(titleDef);
 contact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
```

It is also strange that you can retrieve the [Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.completename.title%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) as a first-class property, but you cannot assign it (*since it's a complex type*). They could have made this easier for us.

```
var title = contact.CompleteName.Title;
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. I was banging my head on this issue for far too long.