# How to set the contact Email1DisplayName using the EWS Java API (Exchange Web Service)?

Tags: exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I just figured out how to set the title (see [How to set the contact title using the EWS Java API (Exchange Web Service)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612782/how-to-set-the-contact-title-using-the-ews-java-api-exchange-web-service)). Now I am trying to set the email 1 display name.

If I use the exposed API Contact.getEmailAddresses().setEmailAddress(), the display name is automatically set to be the same as the email address (and it overrides my extended properties).

So now I am trying to set the complete email information via extended properties. It almost works, except when I look at the address book, the name and display name are empty.

I have a feeling that this is related to the Email1OriginalEntryId property, which I do not know how to set correctly.

Any ideas?

My current attempt looks like this:

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1DisplayName = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8080, MapiPropertyType.String);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1AddressType = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8082, MapiPropertyType.String);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1EmailAddress = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8083, MapiPropertyType.String);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalDisplayName = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8084, MapiPropertyType.String);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalEntryId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8085, MapiPropertyType.Binary);

ExchangeService mailbox = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
mailbox.setUrl(new URL("https://remote.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx").toURI());
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("user.name", "pw", "domain");
mailbox.setCredentials(credentials);

Contact c = new Contact(mailbox);
c.setGivenName("GivenName");
c.setSurname("Surname");

//    c.getEmailAddresses().setEmailAddress(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, new EmailAddress("AB12@B12.com"));

c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1AddressType, "SMTP");
c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1EmailAddress, "A12@B12.com");
c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalDisplayName, "A12@B12.com");
c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1DisplayName, "A12 B12 (A12@B12.com)");
//    c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalEntryId, ???);

c.save(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to believe, but after almost a week of fighting with this, I finally figured it out. Tested only on Exchange 2007.

Note that this only works if you set every single extended property like in this example and do not use Contact.getEmailAddresses().setEmailAddress().

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1DisplayName = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8080, MapiPropertyType.String);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1AddressType = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8082, MapiPropertyType.String);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1EmailAddress = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8083, MapiPropertyType.String);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalDisplayName = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8084, MapiPropertyType.String);

ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalEntryId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(//
    UUID.fromString("00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8085, MapiPropertyType.Binary);

ExchangeService mailbox = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
mailbox.setUrl(new URL("https://remote.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx").toURI());
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("user.name", "pw", "domain");
mailbox.setCredentials(credentials);

String FIRST = "First";
String LAST = "Last";
String FIRST_LAST = FIRST + " " + LAST; // "First Last"
String EMAIL = "first.last@email.com";
String DISPLAY_NAME = FIRST + " " + LAST + " (" + EMAIL + ")"; // "First Last (first.last@email.com)"

Contact c = new Contact(mailbox);
c.setGivenName(FIRST);
c.setSurname(LAST);
c.setFileAs(FIRST_LAST);

// don't use this
//    c.getEmailAddresses().setEmailAddress(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, new EmailAddress(EMAIL));

// Address book Name (seem to trigger the whole address book functionality)
c.setSubject(FIRST_LAST);
// Address book email address
c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalDisplayName, EMAIL);
// contact and address book display name
c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1DisplayName, DISPLAY_NAME);

c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1AddressType, "SMTP"); // constant
c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1EmailAddress, EMAIL);

// not needed after all, exchange sets this automatically
//    c.setExtendedProperty(propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalEntryId, ???);

c.save(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);

for(Item item : mailbox.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, new ItemView(1000)))
{
  Contact result = (Contact) item;

  PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
  propertySet.add(propDef_PidLidEmail1AddressType);
  propertySet.add(propDef_PidLidEmail1EmailAddress);
  propertySet.add(propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalDisplayName);
  propertySet.add(propDef_PidLidEmail1DisplayName);
  propertySet.add(propDef_PidLidEmail1OriginalEntryId);

  result = Contact.bind(mailbox, result.getId(), propertySet);

  LOGGER.info("count: " + result.getExtendedProperties().getCount());

  for(ExtendedProperty p : result.getExtendedProperties())
  {
    LOGGER.info(p.toString());
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]